# API Controller to create object at Initialization

Tags: c#, api

I currently have an API Controller named *"People"*, which inherits `ApiController`.

There are multiple `[HttpPost]`/`[HttpGet]` methods within the controller. Each one uses the same start up. I.e.:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(@"{personID}"]
public async SavePerson(int personID, [FromBody] PersonObject sentPerson) {
    // Here is the initialization method that goes and gets a person
    // dependent on if they have a record already
    var getPerson = _personRepo.GetPerson(personID); 
    // some code here
}
```

Each method uses the same `getPerson` method in the repository. However within `MVCControllers` you can call multiple `overrides` such as `OnActionExecuting` etc.

Is there a way, on initialization of the `APIController` that I can run:

```
var getPerson = _personRepo.GetPerson(personID);
```

before any of the methods within the *"People"* class are run? This means I do not have to rewrite this method above repeatedly for every new `Route`.

Comment: you should have a look at ActionFilter

Comment: What about using the constructor of your controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Person` property for your class and an `ActionFilter` that sets that property:

**ActionFilter:**

```
public class MyActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        //Add other criterias and required null checkings here

        //Find the person id from action arguments
        int personID = Convert.ToInt32(actionContext.ActionArguments["personID"]);
        var _personRepo = new PersonRepository();

        //Get the controller instance that is running and set the Person property
        ((People)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller).Person = _personRepo.GetPerson(personID); 
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[MyActionFilter]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    //your actions
}
```

Then decorate your controller or your actions that you need with `[MyActionFilter]`

Then in any of your actions that are decorated with `[MyActionFilter]`, you can use `this.Person`.